# Isolate "@" character on keyUp for @mentions functionality

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, dom-events

I'm building a basic @mention system using Vue and Vanilla JS, but am struggling to isolate the "@" character specifically.

In my template:

```
<trix-editor
    ref="trix"
    @keyup="listenForUser"
></trix-editor>
```

And in my JS:

```
listenForUser(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 50 && e.shiftKey == true) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Initially, I was listening only for `e.keyCode == 50`, but "50" corresponds both to "@" and "2", so I was trigging the mention unintentionally.

I've added in the `e.shiftKey` to try to isolate the "@" character, but because of the `keyUp` event, my user has to release the "@" key before the "shift" key—otherwise, it doesn't pass the conditional.

Is there a way to either:

- Isolate the "@" character using a single condition
- Change the event listener, so that the order of the keys doesn't matter. The old `keyPress` method would do what I need, [but that's been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress).

Comment: What about different keybord layouts? The `@` character is not produced the same in all keyboard layouts. I feel this approach is futile. Better to check `onChange` instead.

Comment: what kind of functionality are you after? ie similar to facebook where when you type @ a list of names pop up? I agree with Sani, you might want to consider using @change and checking if '@' is in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future folks, here's what I ended up doing. Trix has a proprietary event listener called "trix-change" that watches for **any** change to the editor itself. This gets us around the issues with keyup v. keydown.

Once the event listener is triggered, I can look to see if the last character typed matches my trigger, and if so, initialize my search. This is a keyboard-agnostic approach that gets us around all the various keycode issues.

Code below:

```
editor.addEventListener('trix-change', e => {

    // Get contents of editor to a string
    let content = editor.getDocument().toString();

    // Get cursor position, and use it to determine the last character typed
    let cursorPosition = this.$refs.trix.editor.getPosition();
    let lastCharacterTyped = content.substring(cursorPosition - 1, cursorPosition);

    // If last character matches my trigger, init my search
    if (lastCharacterTyped == "@") {
        // Do Search Stuff
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check `e.key` (instead of `e.keyCode`) for `'@'`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Comment: Yep—I'd thought of that, too, but support for e.key appears uneven, especially in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.shift` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#System-Modifier-Keys) along with the keycode in the directive:

```
<trix-editor @keyup.shift.50="listenForUser" />
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    mention() {
      console.log('mention')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.3/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" @keyup.shift.50="mention">
</div>
```

Comment: What about different keyboard layouts? The `@` character is not produced the same in all keyboard layouts. In an English layout this would work. But in a Swedish layout it wouldn't since `@` is produced with `AltGr + 2` (or `Ctrl + Alt + 2`) compared to the English `Shift + 2` (which in Swedish layout produces `"`).

Comment: The question calls out keycode `50`, so I assume only the English layout is in scope (perhaps that's the only layout that applies for intended user base).

Answer (score -1):

<input v-on:keydown.@="functionFoo"> if the user submitted @ v-on:keydown.@ called function Foo and functionsFoo(inputInfo) received all information about input, for example inputInfo.srcElement.selectionEnd, inputInfo.srcElement.value etc ... we don't need to write any if-s for filtering @ symbol. v-on:keydown.@
Its means function will cold only submitting @ symbol.
[enter link description here](https://vuejsexamples.net/vuejs-events/)

```
<trix-editor ref="trix" @keydown.@="functionFoo"></trix-editor>
```

and your JS function

```js
functionFoo = (inputInfo) => { // todo ... }
```

Comment: Please explain your solution: what is the change and why does it fix the problem?

Comment: <input v-on:keydown.@="functionFoo"> if the user submitted @  v-on:keydown.@ called function Foo and functionsFoo(inputInfo) received all information about input,  for example inputInfo.srcElement.selectionEnd, inputInfo.srcElement.value etc ...